# Django - Passing exceptions in large try block without skipping whole block?

Tags: django, exception, view, django-views, try-catch

I have a view in django which gathers a lot of data depending on user input. Sometimes, not all of the data will be available for the specific query. I currently have large try blocks, but it is less than ideal as it will skip the whole block and not show any data.

Is there any way to continue past the errors without having to do a ton of individual try blocks? Here is a much shorter example to show what I currently have.

```
try:
   year1 = income[0]['date']
   year2 = income[1]['date']
   year3 = income[2]['date']
   year4 = income[3]['date']
   year5 = income[4]['date']
except Exception as e:
   pass
```

This will pass the whole block if year5 is unavailable. One solution would be to put each year in it's own try block, but that would add 100s of lines of code if not thousands. It would be great if there was a simple way to maintain the data that is successfully collected, and pass the ones that throw an exception (or give them a default value).

Thanks!

Comment: `income[0]`, `income[1]`,... clearly you would benefit from a _loop_, yes?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, you just made my code A LOT more efficient! New developer and I didn't realize I was doing it the longest way possible

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give them a default value, you could use the `get` method of dictionaries:

```
year1 = income[0].get('date')
```

This would be the best way to do this, you want to get the 'date' key if it exists, or None otherwise.

An exception is more useful for error management than conditional branching.